# How to Run or Start Play framework project through a Java Main method

Tags: java, java-8, playframework

I started a play framework project and I need to run it through the java class main method.
Here is my Java Class.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Menu");
        System.out.println("Press A to add");
        System.out.println("Press D to Delete");
        System.out.println("Press V to View");
        System.out.println("Press G to Start Server");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please Enter Your Select: ");
        String select = scanner.nextLine();


        switch (select){
            case "A":
                // add method
                break;
            case "D":
                // delete method
                break;
            case "V":
                // view method
                break;
            case "G":
                // start server
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Something went wrong!");
        }
    }
}
```

What should come to the start server method ???

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code to open the port of active localhost server.

```
Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
URI url = new URI("http://localhost:9000/");
desktop.browse(url);
```

Or else, if you need to access terminal commands then try this; but make sure your play project directory path. Now possibly run sbt commands inside java console using this.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;



public class Cmd {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime()
                .exec("cmd /c dir", null, new File("C:\\Users\\"));
        //.exec("sh -c ls", null, new File("Pathname")); for non-Windows users
        printResults(process);
    }

    private static void printResults(Process process) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do is, is to run the `play.core.server.ProdServerStart` directly. In the end that's the entrypoint that the generated shell script is using as well:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ProdServerStart.main(args);
}
```

If you need more customization, or access to the server "process" object, you should call `ProdServerStart.start(...)` instead.

If you need even more customization, just replicate what the `ProdServerStart` class is doing.
Basically, first create an application. The `play.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder` is probably your friend here.
Next, create Server object to actually host the application on a server port.